# Making the snake grow consistently in the game of Snake

Tags: c#

I'm trying to program a simple game of Snake, but I'm having trouble making the snake grow consistently after each piece of food is eaten. The first one that's eaten adds a segment correctly, but 2+ pieces don't.

I think the problem is in the positioning of each segment. In my code, I list `SegmentX` and `SegmentY`, which contain the snake's coordinates when it eats a piece of food, and I list new coordinates in a `foreach` loop. What would cause this to fail after the first piece of food is eaten?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Zmijice
{
    enum SnakeControl
    {
        Right,Left,Up,Down,Stop
    }    

    public partial class Zmijice : Form
    {
        private int snakeX;
        private int snakeY;

        private int newX;
        private int newY;

        private int foodX;
        private int foodY;

        private const int height=20;
        private const int width=20;

        private List<int> SegmentX = new List<int>();
        private List<int> SegmentY = new List<int>();

        Random rnd = new Random();        

        private SnakeControl Position;

        public Zmijice()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();

            RandomFoodPosition();
            RandomSnakePosition();

            Position = SnakeControl.Stop;
        }

        public void RandomFoodPosition()
        {
            foodX = rnd.Next(1, 20) * 20;
            foodY = rnd.Next(1, 20) * 20;
        }

        public void RandomSnakePosition()
        {
            snakeX = rnd.Next(1, 20) * 20;
            snakeY = rnd.Next(1, 20) * 20;
        }

        private void Tajmer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Position == SnakeControl.Stop)
            {
            }

            else if (Position == SnakeControl.Right)
            {                
                snakeX += 20;
            }

            else if (Position == SnakeControl.Left)
            {
                snakeX -= 20;
            }

            else if (Position == SnakeControl.Up)
            {
                snakeY -= 20;
            }

            else if (Position == SnakeControl.Down)
            {
                snakeY += 20;
            }

            Invalidate();
        }    
        private void Zmijice_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
            {
                Position = SnakeControl.Down;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
            {
                Position = SnakeControl.Up;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                Position = SnakeControl.Right;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                Position = SnakeControl.Left;
            }
        }
        private void Zmijice_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {   
            //if snake eaten food
            //int counter = 0;
            if (snakeX==foodX && snakeY==foodY)
            {   
                //new food position
                foodX = rnd.Next(1, 20);
                foodX = foodX * 20;
                foodY = rnd.Next(1, 20);
                foodY = foodY * 20;

                //counter++;

                //grow up snake
                SegmentX.Add(snakeX);
                SegmentY.Add(snakeY);

                //movement for new snake part
                if (Position == SnakeControl.Left)
                {
                    newX = snakeX+20;
                    newY = snakeY;                                       
                }
                if (Position == SnakeControl.Right)
                {
                    newX = snakeX-20;
                    newY = snakeY;                    
                }
                if (Position == SnakeControl.Up)
                {
                    newX = snakeX;
                    newY = snakeY+20;                  
                }
                if (Position == SnakeControl.Down)
                {
                    newX = snakeX;
                    newY = snakeY-20;                    
                }
            }        

            //render snake parts
            foreach (int k in SegmentX)
            {
               foreach (int l in SegmentY)
               {
                  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, newX, newY, width, height);
               }
            }

            //new position is equal old position
            newX = snakeX;
            newY = snakeY;               

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkRed, snakeX, snakeY, width, height);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Aqua, foodX, foodY, width, height); 
        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a struct in .NET called `Point` that would be of great use here.  It'd save you having an X and Y for everything, and you'd only need one segment list.

Comment: You have fun writing code - you ought to debug it yourself. That's the rules.

Comment: Define the segments as their own class. Each instance can store their position. When "moving" the snake, update each segment's position, starting from the end/last, to be the same value as the segment before them. When you reach the starting/first segment, move it to the new position that they player indicated. When eating a food, add a new segment instance at the end.

Comment: Your snake only grows "once", because all its additional segments are at the same position.

Comment: Side note: you may want to consider making some of your past questions as answered. The amount of effort people are willing to put into answering your questions when they aren't likely to be widely useful to others will scale accordingly.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips hmm yes it's smarter for use, but i don't think that is "Point" solve for mine problem.

Comment: -1  IMHO, this isn't a great question for StackOverflow. You are asking for help in debugging specific code. How would the answer be useful to anyone else? Better to ask on some programming FORUM.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve

I asked on two, but there are no answer. 
This is not solved still, i don't understand you guys :(

Comment: @DocNet - you don't update the position of the segments when the snake moves. You just loop through the two lists, but display them all at the old position of the snake head. You need to update the position of each segment when the snake moves. The last one get's the position of the second to last one, the second to last one get's the position of the third to last one and so on. Also, `foreach`ing over both lists like that will not work. If you have 4 segments, you will be drawing 16 times...

Comment: @Docnet: This site exists to serve future people with the same problem as much as to solve your problems.

Answer (score 3):

This only will draw one rectangle on top of the previous for every segment in your snake:

```
//render snake parts
foreach (int k in SegmentX)
{
     foreach (int l in SegmentY)
     {
         e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Orange, newX, newY, width, height);
     }
}
```

So the number of segments doesn't change the snake's length...

(Except when you go from 0 parts to 1, since the foreach executes)

You should use a `for` loop and move the rectangle next to the previously drawn one. I'm sure you can figure that part out quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps consider keeping track of when food is eaten. Instead of adding a new segment when food is eaten, when you are removing an old segment check if there is recently eaten food. If there is, reset the eaten food flag and skip removing the segment.

Short of a complete rewrite, I can't see another easy way to salvage what you've got there.